# Lubuntu alternate and ubuntu minimal install hangs

Tags: installation, partitioning

i'm trying to install lubuntu/ubuntu minimal on an old machine from usb but the install hangs right after choosing how to partition. I have tried both lubuntu an ubuntu minimal install. Any suggestions on how to solve this? Maby there is some old files on the hdd causing the problem, if that is the case how can i prepare it for install?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sergei. Have you [verified MD5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM/) on your iso? Have you gone over this [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall)?To be honest I have never used the minimal install, but I know that the alternate install has an option to check the disk on the main menu, if so run that as well. Should the MD5sum and the disk check come back good then you will have ruled those out. If these do not solve your issue then what are the specs of your computer? I know you referred to it as "old" but, I have personally used the alternate install iso several times on my Pentium 3 1.2 ghz 512 mb ram desktop and it has never failed (Ubuntu, Xubuntu,and Lubuntu).